# Critical error in Wordpress Blog

Tags: wordpress

I have just updated All in one SEO plugin in my WP blog. And suddnly my blog is not work. Following error messages is coming when i am opening:

Warning: require_once(aioseop_module_class.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Hosting\10904842\html\ravidesai\blog\wp-content\plugins\all-in-one-seo-pack\aioseop_class.php on line 8

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'aioseop_module_class.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\Hosting\10904842\html\ravidesai\blog\wp-content\plugins\all-in-one-seo-pack\aioseop_class.php on line 8

Please help

Thanks

Comment: disable or remove the plugin

Comment: If you used FTP to upload your plugin ,ensure that all the plugin files have been copied across to your server.

Comment: @suspectus I can not login in Admin Also.

Comment: @Anand I have not upload FTP.

Comment: If you don't have FTP, you gotta ask for support to your hosting provider...

Comment: I have FTP but i have not uploaded plug in. This is happen after i update plug in via WP Admin.